# Не запускается Tomcat из NetBeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

NetBeans 8 стоял раньше, поставил Tomcat. Создал сервер, всё настроил по инструкциям, кавычки в `catalina.bat` убрал. По итогу при попытке развёртки проекта Tomcat вроде бы сервер запускает, ошибок не выдаёт, последняя строка лога:

> INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup
>   in 1554 ms

Но проект пишет *"Ожидание Tomcat..."*, а через минуту где-то аварийно завершается и выдаёт *"Не удалось запустить Tomcat*.

> C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\servlet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045:
>   Ошибка при развертывании: Не удалось запустить Tomcat."

В интернете решение проблемы, конечно, искал.

Ничего не помогло. Я в отчаянии.

Comment: добавьте лог Tomcat файл в вопрос.

Comment: настройка сервера в NetBeans элементарная - назвал, указал путь к нему, ввел логин и пароль (если нужно деплоить приложения на сервер) и все..

    какие еще кавычки ? если запустить сервер по startup.bat он запускается ?